# Cannot connect to ganache-cli remotely

Tags: metamask, ganache, ganache-cli

Currently working on a NFT project for myself. Felt it would be easier, for myself, to view the NFTs within Metamask on my phone. Interacting with smart contracts directly... might be the only way... but it takes me far longer to accomplish.

I have two instances of ganache-cli that I start with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ganache-cli -d --db /[[home]]/.ganache_chaindb -i 1337 --accounts 10 -h 0.0.0.0 --deterministic --mnemonic="[[...]]" &
ganache-cli -d --db /[[home]]/.ganache_chaindb_alt -i 5777 -p 7545 --accounts 10 -h 0.0.0.0 --deterministic --mnemonic="[[...]]" &
```

I tested the instances with `curl` using the following commands:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"net_version","params":[],"id":67}' localhost:8545
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"net_version","params":[],"id":67}' 192.168.x.x:8545
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"net_version","params":[],"id":67}' localhost:7545
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"net_version","params":[],"id":67}' 192.168.x.x:7545
```

All responses contained the proper `chainId` value. My local MetaMask browser extension connects to Ganache. My phone does not. Again the purpose of using my phone was to view the NFT and the changes I made to the image under various conditions.

I do not have an active firewall running. What am I missing? Specifically MetaMask (on phone) is stating: "Could not fetch chain ID. Is your RPC URL correct?"

Comment: Is your remote machine running in cloud?

Comment: No it's just a local network: phone, router, laptop.